# How to Load Images from a RSS Feed using Google Feed API?

Tags: javascript, rss, google-feed-api

I'm not able to load the images using Google Feed API, I'm using the mediaGroup to load images.

*This is the javascript code I've written for fetching the feed*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("feeds", "1");
function initialize() 
   {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://techzei.com/feed");
    feed.setNumEntries(14);
    feed.load(function (result) {
        if (!result.error) 
        {
            result.feed.entries.forEach(function(entry)
            {
              $('#feed').append('<div class="card"><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a><p>' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p><br><p>'+entry.publishedDate+'"<img src="'+ entry.mediaGroups+'"/></div>');
            });
        }
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

The html

```
<article id="feed"></article>
```

All the images I get right now are "undefined". Should I be doing something else? The [Google Feed API dev](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide) didn't throw much light on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feed doesn't seem to have any `mediaGroup` entries, that is the reason you get undefined in your result, but you can extract the images from the `entry.content` using jQuery.

Puts image urls to an array and shows first found image (or none):

```
var content = document.createElement("content");
content.innerHTML = entry.content;                   
var images = $(content).find('img').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src')
}).get();
$('#feed').append('<div class="card"><a href="' + entry.link + '">' +
    entry.title + '</a><p>' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p><br><p>'+ 
    entry.publishedDate +'</p>' + 
    (images.length == 0 ? '' :'<img src="'+ images[0] +'"/>') + '</div>');
```

Shows all images, by appending the img tags to a variable:

```
var content = document.createElement("content");
content.innerHTML = entry.content;
var images = "";
$(content).find('img').each(function() {  
    images += this.outerHTML;
}); 
$('#feed').append('<div class="card"><a href="' + entry.link + '">' +
    entry.title + '</a><p>' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p><br><p>' +
    entry.publishedDate + '</p>' + images +'</div>');
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost solved the problem but I wasn't able to get the featured image from the feed. The posts which only had a featured image and no other image in the post got printed as (undefined)

Comment: Not all feed items in Techzei's feed have images. You can check that from the source of the rss feed. I updated the first code sample to not print "undefined" if no images found.

Comment: They all do have images but not in the content entry. The featured images don't seem to get included in the content of a wordpress feed. Any other options ?

Comment: Here is one item from the rss feed: http://pastebin.com/NKnyDpCk I don't find any image links there, not in content or any other fields. Maybe that blog post should be updated in Wordpress to have a certain featured image so that it would be included in the feed?

Comment: I've added the featured image to be added to the content description on the rss feed end. The images still don't seem to be loading.

Comment: @JashJacob can you post the code or code example of how you are trying to do it?

Comment: I've added the featured image by adding the post thumbnail into the content like this `$content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' ) . '' . $content;`

Comment: @JashJacob I updated the answer a bit. Now it should pick all the images from feed entries.

Comment: It works now. Could you explain the change you made ?

Comment: @JashJacob I basically added two new rows at the beginning of the code examples. I place the `entry.content` to a HTML document object and then search it. For some reason the earlier version didn't find the first image of an entry.