# How to parse the RSS using google api or any other techinques

Tags: google-api, rss

I want to parse the below mentioned RSS in order to get the title, description, image and date. Currently i'm able to get the all other details except image. Im using google api feed to parse the rss. Please can anyone me in this context.
RSS:https://news.google.com/news/feeds?cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&q=cricket&output=rss

```
// Google Feed API: https://developers.google.com/feed/
// Inspiration: http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/build-an-automated-rss-feed-list-with-jquery/

function parseFeed(url, container) {
    $.ajax({
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // log object data in console
            console.log(data.responseData.feed);
            // append feed link and title in container
            $(container).append('<a href="' + url + '"><span class="iconicstroke-rss-alt"></span></a>');
            $(container).append('<h1 class="feed">' + data.responseData.feed.title + '</h1>');
            // for each entry... *
            $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (key, value) {
                // * create new date object and pass in entry date
                var date = new Date(value.publishedDate);
               // var thumbnail = entry.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url;
                // * create months array
                var months = new Array(12);
                months[0] = 'January';
                months[1] = 'February';
                months[2] = 'March';
                months[3] = 'April';
                months[4] = 'May';
                months[5] = 'June';
                months[6] = 'July';
                months[7] = 'August';
                months[8] = 'September';
                months[9] = 'October';
                months[10] = 'November';
                months[11] = 'December';
                // * parse month, day and year
                var month = date.getMonth();
                var day = date.getDate();
                var year = date.getFullYear();

                // * assign entry variables
                var title = '<h3 class="title"><a href="' + value.link + '" target="_blank">' + value.title + '</a></h3>';
                var time = '<p class="time">' + months[month] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year + '</p>';
                var snippet = '<p class="snippet">' + value.contentSnippet + '</p>';
                var img = '<p class="snippet">' + value.thumbnail + '</p>';
                var entry = '<div class="entry">' + title + time + snippet + '</div>';
                // * append entire entry in container
                $(container).append(entry);
            });
        },
        // if there's an error... *
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            // * log error message in console
            console.log(errorThrown);
            // * show error message
            alert('Houston, we have a problem.');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    parseFeed('https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=en&hl=in&q=aishwarya%20rai&output=rss', '#csstricks');
});
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, What programming language are you using? And where's your code?

Comment: Im using jquery. below is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your script

```
var content = document.createElement("content");
content.innerHTML = value.content; 
var images = "";
$(content).find('img').each(function() {  
    images += this.outerHTML;
});
var img = '<p class="snippet">' + images + '</p>';
```

Same answer as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26369373/989257

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/janih/pen/JdPMZX

Comment: Awesome, even i was looking samething. Thanks a lot Janih :)